# Trigger a JQuery function when a POST request is received from a remot server

Tags: php, jquery, post

A remote server sends a POST message to mypage.php
mypage.php then process the received message and store it on my database, then I want to trigger a JQuery function every time the message is received
Knowing that mypage.php is already opened on my browser when the POST message is received

Thank you

Comment: You can just echo out the JavaScript, although this doesn't seem like the best option. Why not send the POST via AJAX, and call your jQuery function in the AJAX callback?

Comment: The post is sent by an outside server, I don't have control over what I receive

Comment: If the POST is sent from a remote server, than users wont be interacting with the page anyway. What is the purpose of the jQuery function?

Comment: The POST is sent from a remote server to mypage.php

Comment: You'll need either long-polling or websockets.

Comment: First, your browser views the page, and then either opens a socket conenction or starts longpolling. If using longpolling, you will need it hitting a script that checks whether or not a POST has happened to that page yet, and if it has, send the message. If using websockets, you just broadcast a message whenever a post is received.

Comment: Is it worth doing or making a Jquery loop that checks for any new updates every 3 seconds for example is a common way of doing it ?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do. I use same page processing though.
php (where submit is the name of the submit button on your form):

```
if( isset($_POST['submit']) ){
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>someJSFunction();</script>";
}
```

EDIT: Sorry, my bad. I fixed the quotes in the echo.

Comment: Sorry I may not well explained the problem : 
A remote server sends a POST message to mypage.php so I don't have any form on mypage.php

Comment: This is invalid HTML. Fix the quotes.

Comment: @Tarik Mokafih I don't see why this wouldn't work for that. It will run that js whenever it recieves POST data from another page.

Comment: I replaced 'submit' by my variables names but didn't work, I need to detect a message whenever it arrives, I don't know if such real time stuff could be done, or if I should put a loop that checks for updates every 3 seconds for example

Comment: @Tarik Mokafih instead of checking for the submit button you could check for whatever you are trying to post.

Comment: This is what I did, I think that php script will be executed only when mypage.php is launched, but not if it was already opened on my browser